# Matlab probability loop

Tags: matlab

I have a question regarding calculating probabilites using for-loops.

Example:

A gameshow has 70 numbers, where 20 are drawn, 11 is the maximum amount of correct numbers (and give the highest prize).

Now, I'd like to present the probabilities of each outcome as a vector, which gets it's input from a for-loop.
My probability knowledge is a bit rusty so forgive any mistakes.

What I have tried so far:

```
K = 11;
format long;
p = zeros(1,K+1) %my vector

for i = 0:K
p(i+1) = 1/nchoosek(70,i+1)
end
sum(p)
```

However, if A="win", the complement of A is not accounted for. What I'd like to achieve:
the probability of i correct numbers, in rising index, ex:

p(1)="0 correct numbers"

p(2)="1 correct number"

p(K+1)="11 correct numbers"

The problem im having is getting the for loop to assign p(1) correctly while also having the others correct. Is it possible to do with 1 loop, and if so, how?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a smaller example? For instance, with 7, 4, 2 instead of 70, 20, 11, what exact values would be the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your probability calculations need to change.  For instance, when you are calculating p(1) to represent 0 correct guesses, you are just doing 1/nchoosek(1,0).  This will not represent the probablity you want.  I believe what you want is the total ways of picking 20 cards from 70 in your denominator each time (nchoosek(70,20)).  In fact you should assign this to some value outside your loop:

```
    event_space= nchoosek(70,20);
```

For there to be zero correct cards, you'll need to find out how many ways you can pick all the *wrong* cards (20 out of the 59 total).  This will be nchoosek(59,20).

Then, you probability will be:

```
    p(0) = nchoosek(59,20)/event_space
```

Similar calculations can be done for choosing the varying amount of correct numbers (for 1 correct, you are picking 19 wrong cards instead of 20, but then you have 11 possible correct cards... it gets tricky!).  I imagine the correct calculations can be put into a loop in the way you have, although the 0 case might be a special case that should be done outside the loop.

(someone please correct me if my probability is also rusty!).